# Service Unavailable: DOCS when copying Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Suddenly encountered one issue where Google DOCS service fails after making some calls to copy elements.
Funny thing is that it actually copies the first element, but when it goes for the second loop within the "for" it fails giving this error:
Service unavailable: Documents

This script used to work fine for a few months as we have it published within our company.
Suddenly last week it stopped working for all the users regardless of their browser etc...

It is a script linked to a Google Spreadsheet (where it gets the information to generate a Google Docs). But it also fails if I execute it, or debug it, from the Script console as well.

What I've tried after it started failing is to add a couple of lines to saveAndClose the document in case there was an issue with too many calls or buffering.

I've checked and the project does have access to Google Docs, Drive and Maps API.

The elements to be copied are correct, as I can do Logger.Log with them...

It just fails when it has to copy the actual element (appendParagraph, append ListItem, etc...)

I've enabled StackDriver logs and errors but it doesn't show any logs in the console, just "failed".

Any hint or directions will be very much appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
function copyDescription(ID,newDoc,newDocID){
var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(ID).getBody();
newDoc.saveAndClose();
newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID);
var docbody = newDoc.getBody();

var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();


//Run through template document and copies to the new one
for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
    var attributes = otherBody.getChild(j).getAttributes();
    var type = element.getType();


    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        if (element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() != 0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
            var pictattr = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getAttributes();
            var blob = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();
        }
        else { 
            docbody.appendParagraph(element);
        }
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        docbody.appendTable(element);
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        docbody.appendListItem(element);
    else
        throw new Error("Unsupported element type: "+type);

    newDoc.saveAndClose();
}
```

}

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. When you confirm the modification points of Google Document and/or script before and after `Suddenly last week it stopped`, what differences did you confirm? 2. When owner of the Document run the script, does the error occur? 3. Where line does the error occur? 4. About `the second loop`, what content is there at `otherBody.getChild(1)`? 5. Can you provide the whole script and sample Document for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. If these were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for your prompt reply...
There were no differences on the script as I'm the only one with access to edit it. I did double check there were no modifications on the day it started failing.
Yes the error does occur when I run it (doc owner).
In this case, the error is occurring in this line:
docbody.appendParagraph(element)

Running a few tests I've identified that in the second loop the error occurs when the paragraph has inline, break or wrapped images in it (but before it was running fine)

My guess now is that google has recently changed how images are treated?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `There were no differences on the script as I'm the only one with access to edit it.` and `the error occurs when the paragraph has inline, break or wrapped images in it`, your script had worked for both situation before. But now, the error occurs although the Document and script are not changed from before. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I further identified the problem happens only when:
Inside a paragraph, or inside a list item, there are either wrapped images or break images.
Apparently with inline images it works fine...
Any idea how to manipulate those? It's important for me to keep the format. Up until one week ago those were copied along to the new document just fine...
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `There were no differences on the script as I'm the only one with access to edit it.` and `the error occurs when the paragraph has inline, break or wrapped images in it`, your script had worked for both situation before. But now, the error occurs although the Document and script are not changed from before. For this situation, you say `Yes that is correct.`. But in your latest replying, it seems that it is different from above. So I'm confusing about your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Ivanovix Could [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141417903) be your case? If so , it is probably a bug.

Comment: Hi Jescanellas,
The error looks the same. Different way to invoke it, but looks like when it catches something it can't handle just gives you Service Unavailable...

@Tanaike I managed to reproduce it only under certain conditions, but my statement prevails as before it was working just fine... I think Google just changed the way it handles wrapped or break images to be copied with Google Apps Script...

Comment: @Ivanovix Running into this issue myself with a `body.appendParagraph(paragraph.copy());` call, when it was working up until just a couple of weeks ago (probably coinciding with your issue). Did you figure it out?

Comment: hi Ian, does your Paragraph contain images or drawings? Give it a test without those, just text.... If it works it might be related...
My workaround so far, definitely not nice, is to strip the paragraphs of images, copy them, and then add then manually...
Now it takes a lot of time to execute but it's working right now...

Comment: I ran into this on `row.appendTableCell(previous_cell.copy());` when there was an image embedded in the table cell.  Thanks @Ivanovix.

Comment: The App script doesn't know how to handle images that are aligned with "Wrap Text" setting. Rather use Inline.