# Why does copying a table in Google Docs not copy embedded graphics?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

This bit of Google Apps Script code

```js
    for (let el = 0; el < tempDocBody.getNumChildren(); el++) {
      const elem = tempDocBody.getChild(el);
      Logger.log(
        "ProcessMainTable [%s] %s %s",
        el,
        elem.getType().toString(),
        elem.asText().getText(),
      );
      switch (elem.getType()) {
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
          target.getBody().insertTable(offset++, elem.asTable().copy());
          break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
          target.getBody().insertParagraph(offset++, elem.asParagraph().copy());
          break;
      }
    }
```

works fine EXCEPT that the image that is embedded in one of the TABLE cells doesn't get copied to the target. Everything else goes over nicely e.g. fonts and formatting. Isn't the `.copy()` supposed to be "deep"?

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- In your situation, the table cells have the inline image. When you copy the table from the source Document to the target Document, the images are not copied.
- You want to copy the table to the target Document by including the inline images.

For this, how about this modification? In this case, it seems that the inline images cannot be directly copied using `copy()`. So as a workaround, after the table was copied from the source Document to the target Document, how about putting the images from the source Document to the target Document?

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
target.getBody().insertTable(offset++, elem.asTable().copy());
```

To:

```
var srcTable = elem.asTable().copy();
var dstTable = target.getBody().insertTable(offset++, srcTable);
for (var i = 0; i < srcTable.getNumRows(); i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < srcTable.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
    var cell = srcTable.getCell(i, j);
    for (var k = 0; k < cell.getNumChildren(); k++) {
      var paragraph = cell.getChild(k).asParagraph();
      for (var l = 0; l < paragraph.getNumChildren(); l++) {
        var child = paragraph.getChild(l);
        if (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
          var srcImg = child.asInlineImage();
          dstTable.getCell(i, j).getChild(k).asParagraph().clear().insertInlineImage(l, srcImg.getBlob()).setWidth(srcImg.getWidth()).setHeight(srcImg.getHeight());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I have searched about this issue at the Google issue tracker. But I couldn't find it. So how about reporting this to the issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

#### References:

- [Class Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table)
- [insertInlineImage(childIndex, image)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertinlineimagechildindex,-image)

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, sir, and I am delighted to see your name again in this context. I have been experimenting and we have come to the same conclusion so I will give your answer the tick of approval.

Comment: Oh dear, now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054839/service-unavailable-docs-when-copying-google-docs is impacting

Comment: @bugmagnet Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.